# jquery rewrite search in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, select, html, each

How to make this format:

```
$('a[href*=wikipedia.org/][rel]').each(function()

But with a div instead of a href
    $('#block_profile[rel]').each(function () {
```

Anyone can show how and clarify why? the problem is my custom 2nd line of code does an action on every block_profile there are 10 of them on a page, if I click the 10nd the action is executed 10 times, If I click the 8th block_profile than the action is triggered 8times, whats a solution to fix this? thx!

​
My HTML is like this:

```
<div rel="2" id="block_profile" class="block_profile">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: You have to post html part. To show what's processing.

Comment: You have duplicate IDs? Your selector is starting with a "#" which says, get me the ID "block_profile with relative attribute". Weird.

Comment: Extending on @kitgui.com's comment, duplicate IDs == invalid markup. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to use `class` instead of `id`, because `id` should be unique and `class` can be used for a group and to select all `divs` with `class='block_profile'` and `rel` you can use

```
$('div.block_profile[rel]')
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbWkp/3/) (See in the console)